# Lazy lists with transformations, using generators & iterators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, lazy

I built this very-basic lazy list (I'll add more methods as I need them). You provide it an array, a generator or any iterator. It creates a lazy list, which lets you run a pipeline of transformations in a lazy manner, meaning that they'll only be applied as you pull values out of the list.

Here's the class:

```js
class List {
    static range(start, end) {
        return new List(function* () {
            while (start <= end) {
                yield start++;
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(source) {
        if (typeof source == 'function') {
            this.generator = source;
        } else {
            this.generator = function* () {
                yield* source;
            };
        }
    }

    filter(predicate) {
        return new List(function* () {
            for (const item of this) {
                if (predicate(item)) {
                    yield item;
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    map(mapper) {
        return new List(function* () {
            for (const item of this) {
                yield mapper(item);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    take(size) {
        return new List(function* () {
            for (const item of this) {
                if (size--) {
                    yield item;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator] () {
        yield* this.generator();
    }

    toArray() {
        return [...this];
    }
}
```

Here's a simple example of how to use it:

```js
List.range(1, 10 ** 9)
    .filter(number => number % 10 == 0)
    .map(number => 'Item ' + number)
    .take(5)
    .toArray();
```

Trying the same with a regular array:

```js
Array.from({ length: 10 ** 9 }, (v, i) => i + 1)
     .filter(number => number % 10 == 0)
     .map(number => 'Item ' + number)
     .slice(0, 5);
```

...will run out of memory before it completes.

Comment: Sidenote: not having generator arrow functions saddens me.

Comment: Currently it lacks the very basic list constructor, the `cons` itself (`(:)` in Haskell). Though can be implemented with a function each time, it probably makes sense to make it specific.

Comment: I am curious to see how the reoccurring `return new List(function* ()` code can be reduced. One could probably dynamically define `filter`, `map`, `take` from an array of the inner generator functions. Not sure if this is clean, though, and one loses all the typings (when using TypeScript).

Comment: @ComFreek - I don't think that's possible, since you must `yield`, and the only way to do that is within a generator function. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "One could probably dynamically define `filter`, `map`, `take` from an array of the inner generator functions". There's no array, which is the whole point here. The values are all flowing down one by one.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/70nPzuzp.

Comment: So you're still creating an actual generator function to wrap every operation. I don't see how that's any better than what we have here.

Answer (score 2):

I can not find fault with your code apart from the use of `class` of which i am not a fan.

So I will just present an alternative syntax that gives a little extra encapsulated protection. Its usage is slightly different. `List` is instantiated via a factory and closure holds the generator `list`. I also freeze each instance of List to further protect the state.

It also does not have to mess about with `const list = this` which from your side-note comment is a bit of an annoyance.

```
const lazyList = (() => {

    const range = (start, end) => List(function* () {
       while(start <= end) { yield start++ }
    });    
    function List(source) {
        var list;
        if (typeof source === "function") { list = source }
        else { list = function* () { yield* source } }

        return Object.freeze({
            filter(pred){
                return List(function* () {
                    for (const item of list()) { pred(item) ? yield item : 0 }
                });
            },
            map(map) {
                return List(function* () {
                    for (const item of list()) { yield map(item) }
                });
            },
            take(count) {
                return List(function* () {
                    for (const item of list()) {
                        if (count--) { yield item }
                        else { break }
                    }
                });
            },
            toArray() { return [...list()] },
            *[Symbol.iterator] () { yield* list() }
        });
    } 
    return Object.freeze({range, List});

})();
```

Comment: I wouldn't call using classes a "fault". It's ok for you to prefer a more functional, closure-based approach, but I vastly prefer sticking all my methods on the prototype so that I don't have to recreate them for every single list created.

Comment: Also, I got rid of all the `const list = this` by binding the functions to the current object.